# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration Facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I'm developing a Facebook integrated Android app. I followed this [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso) to the dot. The problem is that I get the following error if the Facebook app is not installed on the device when logging in:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

I implemented Single Sign On as specified in the tutorial. If I run my app on a device with the Facebook app already installed, my app redirects to the Facebook app to sign in. That's fine. However, if the Facebook app is not installed, I get the error. Here's a snapshot:

[image]

which redirects to Web page not available on signing in:

[image]

Edit: I double checked the tutorial and saw this bit about filling a Mobile Web URL which I didn't follow. I'm not quite sure what to enter here. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Seems to have been a bug on Facebook's side. Using the updated repo from github solved the problem.